# fs.writeFileSync - write JSON to file always writes a empty object

Tags: node.js, json, fs

i create a json-object and want to write this down to a json-file, but the object is always empty (?)

```
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/myNewFile.json', JSON.stringify(myObjects));
```

the content of the written file is now `[]`

```
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/myNewFile.json', JSON.stringify({bla: myObjects}));
```

the content of the file is now `{"bla":[]}`

I doublecheck `myObjects` and it is not empty.. it is a array with some objects in it.

why is that? what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
this is the content of `myObjects`:

```js
[ struct: { id: 'struct',
    name: 'Struktur',
    icon: 'fa fa-bullseye',
    properties: [] },
  mp: { id: 'mp',
    name: 'Messpunkt',
    icon: 'fa fa-circle',
    properties: [] },
  '356899e5-d8b0-41aa-b7cd-de2135c5a3db': { id: '356899e5-d8b0-41aa-b7cd-de2135c5a3db',
    name: 'Untermessung',
    icon: 'fa fa-tachometer',
    properties: [] },
  '8d824cfd-584f-40e9-b9fa-78d7fedcc727': { id: '8d824cfd-584f-40e9-b9fa-78d7fedcc727',
    name: 'Kommune',
    icon: 'fa fa-thumb-tack',
    properties: [] },
  '2609b2ac-77aa-42f2-af22-d49fcfc6f0f0': { id: '2609b2ac-77aa-42f2-af22-d49fcfc6f0f0',
    name: 'Bereiche',
    icon: 'fa fa-circle',
    properties: [] },
  'a4ac2e52-da95-412f-b431-499f2eff64da': { id: 'a4ac2e52-da95-412f-b431-499f2eff64da',
    name: 'Gebäude',
    icon: 'fa fa-industry',
    properties: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

Comment: What is the content of `myObjects` ? Make sure the file gets modified, maybe `__dirname ` is not the folder you think it is.

Comment: the file gets written in place correctly.. also `myObjects` is filled with the correct content..  the only problem is, that instead of `myObjects` there is always `[]`

Comment: I userstand that `myObjects` is not empty, but what is its content ? does it also appears empty if you try to use console.log ?

Comment: @Peter OP is trying to stringify *to* JSON, not parse from JSON

Comment: @Seblor .. `console.log(myObjects)` outputs the correct content of `myObjects` .. I check it before fs.writeFileSync() and after ..both are ok

Comment: Again, what is the content of `myObjects` ? Maybe it cannot be converted to string with `JSON.stringify`. We need to know what you are trying to stringify.

Comment: do a `console.dir(myObjects)` and add it to the question.

Comment: I have added the content of `myObjects` to the question